# Adobe connect addin not working and stay on connecting

Tags: adobe-connect

I want use **Adobe Connect 9.6.1** for online meeting and install complete on server.

when connected by chrome browser its worked good but try connect by **adobeconnectaddin** or **Mozil 64x** stay in **connecting...**  and not working.

[image]

What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by a network problem. Make sure that you have ports 1935, 80 and 443 open both ways.

Can you can run connection test https://[your_server_name]/common/help/en/support/meeting_test.htm and post results?